# How to create a "remove_if_not" for a vector<string>

Tags: c++, vector, filter, c++17, erase

I am trying to make something like this:

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), !pointer_to_func), v.end());
```

where **v** is a `vector` of strings, and `pointer_to_func` is my `function-pointer` that looks something like this:

```
bool (*pointer_to_func)(std::string);
```

And I know that the !pointer_to_func is wrong, however, that is the algorithm I am looking to produce somehow given the circumstances.

This is how it is declared in the class :

```
void Place::filter_ss(bool (*n)(std::string)){}; //function pointer labeled FP
```

I have searched all over, and I am not sure what else to do. Given that the function calls for filtering words in a vector to meet substring conditions, I figured remove_if() and copy() mash-up would do the trick however, I was wrong, and all options I have seen are deprecated/removed (i.e. `not1`, `not2`, `ptr_fun`, etc.).

Function is called as such in main program file:

```
int main(){
    //places all push_back into vector v
    Place p(){"Observatory", "Airport", "Delicatessen", "Theater", "Vacation"}; 
    //this function is the pain, it take in the string directly and erases words not containing the substring
    p.filter_ss(at); 
    //for loop should output: Observatory Delicatessen Theater Vacation
    for (size_t x = 0; x < p.v.size(), x++) 
        cout << v[x] << " ";
    ... //Do something
    ... //Do something more
    return 0;
}
```

My code only works with predefined test functions for example:

```
bool st(string str){
    return str.find("st") < string::npos;
}
```

Any assistance/direction would be appreciated.

attempts aren't in order, nor are they alone in their own unique possibilities. These are general ideas of some of the things I have tried:
**1.**

```
void Place::filter_ss(bool (*n)(string)){
    pointer_to_func = n;
    vector<string> temp;
    for(size_t t = 0; t < v.size(); t++){
        if(pointer_to_func(v[t])){
            temp.push_back(v[t]);
        }
    }
    v.clear();
    for(auto s : temp)
        v.push_back(s);
}
```

**2.**

```
void Place::filter_ss(bool (*n)(string)){
    pointer_to_func = n;
    v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), not1(ptr_fun(pointer_to_func))), v.end());
}
```

**3.**

```
void Place::filter_ss(bool (*n)(string)){
    vector<string> temp;
    pointer_to_func = n;
    copy_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), back_inserter(v), pointer_to_func);
}
```

Comment: `eraase(remove_if(...))` removes everything satisfying the predicate. So, negate the predicate.

Comment: That's the catch, I haven't found a way to, I have tried all of the not1, not2, ptr_fun, etc. But will try the answer below by Nicol and get back @Casey

Comment: It worked, test code was broken but all of the methods above worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

The various `std::not` functors were deprecated in C++17 and removed from C++20 because they [added a better, generic alternative: `std::not_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn):

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::not_fn(pointer_to_func), v.end());
```

Comment: This worked! Also 2 of my 3 methods above worked as well @nicol but the test file was broken so myself and a lot of others faced the same issue. Thank you for the heads up and insight